# Azure function apps Subscription topic trigger and BLOB

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

I am new to Azure and checking if anyone can help me on a solution for the below scenario.

Payload(json message) is sent to a BLOB storage and its reference id is sent to Servicebus Topic.
I know how to work Servicebus topic function app trigger but don't know how to search the blob storage using the referenceid(from subscription topic message) and retrieve its associated message from BLOB.

Comment: Instead of saving the reference id in topic message, can't you simply store the blob URL in the message?

Comment: Have you studied [Blob Input Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input)?

Comment: @GauravMantri - yes the reference id is the blob url, i cant find any proer documentation on how to pass the path and read the contents of the file.